# How to apply MID function to range or column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet document. In there I have a column of text. I want to fill another column with substrings from each value from the first column, like this:

```
A       |  B
a.123   |  123
b.456   |  456
c.789   |  789
```

If a value is added to column `A` I want it to automatically appear in column `B`.

I tried (to no avail):

- `=ARRAYFORMULA(MID(A2:A, 3, 3))`
- `=MID(ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A}), 3, 3)`
- `=MID({A2:A}, 3, 3)`

Which formula in the `B2` cell will solve this? Or is it impossible to do from a single cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MID(A1:A; 3; 3))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! I was getting “Result was not automatically expanded, please add more rows” error, and I didn't understand it. It turns out that because I tested in the the cell `B8`, it couldn't display the whole array because of insufficient number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

and this shall work too:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; ".(\d+)")))
```

[image: 0]

or even:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RIGHT(A1:A; 3))
```